# Cannot login to Postgrest database despite setting password for user 'postgres'

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use pgAdmin III to manage my Postgres database.

Here are the commands I've run on my machine:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

Then I installed the pgAdmin III application:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

---

Next I focused on setting my username and password in order to login:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres

Here I set my password
\password postgres
```

Finally I just created my database:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb repairsdatabase
```

---

When I try to login using pgAdmin III, I get the error:

> An error has occurred:
>
> Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

[image]

Comment: How did you set up `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: I didn't set that configuration file at all, the Ubuntu wiki didn't mention it.

Comment: @Serg Please don't take this the wrong way, but if you're working with Postgres you *really* ***need*** to read the [Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/). Saying "The Ubuntu wiki didn't mention" a key aspect of Postgres setup and configuration is like saying "The manual for my Honda Civic didn't include instructions on starting the engines on this Boeing 777" (And that's leaving aside my personal feelings that Ubuntu's documentation is generally awful, whereas the Postgres manual is better than most commercial software I've used...)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a FAQ.

You're connecting via UNIX sockets, and your `pg_hba.conf` is set to use `peer` authentication, so it expects your UNIX user ID to be the same as your PostgreSQL user ID.

Change `pg_hba.conf` to use `md5` for `local` connections, and/or use TCP/IP by specifying "localhost" as the host instead of leaving the host blank. Local TCP/IP connections might be set to use `ident` in `pg_hba.conf` so change that to `md5` if it is and if you want to use password auth.

See [the PostgreSQL manual on `pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for more information, and search Google for your error message.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem now.

It was solved by typing `localhost` to «Host» field at «New Server Registration» dialog.